# A better JSON API for collection of java 1.4 objects

Tags: json, jdk1.4

I am using [JSON-simple API](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EncodingExamples#Example_2-1_-_Encode_a_JSON_array) to convert java object array to JSON string without any success.

The response is weird: [object-name@6ddc07] and I get error on AJAX call.

Is there a better API compatible with JDK 1.4.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: For reference ( im NOT a java guru so im holding my mouth on recommending a library) an array format should appear such as..  name=[ele1,ele2 ele3]

Comment: Thanks for your comment! My java object has like 8 attributes with getter/setters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the [official JSON library](http://www.json.org/java/)?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! Although, I am looking for a jar file so I can test it... Can you point me to a jar download link...

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded the source code: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java , and was able to make it work!

Comment: @jqueryEnthusiast can you provide the jar file.